# Windows XP TEMP profile

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp

Am create a ubuntu server. and add pc to that domain. but each xp users login time create TEMP profiles. Domain Controller Ubuntu with samba. which way solve this problem.

Error message which shows up on the workstation is

> Windows cannot locate the server copy of your roaming profile and is attempting to log you on with your local profile. Changes to the profile will not be copied to the server when you logoff. You may receive this error message because of network problems or insufficient security rights. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator.

Comment: Voting to close. We're going to need a *lot* more information before anyone can help you. (Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more details)

Answer (score 2):

Is this the message you get?

> Your user profile was not loaded correctly! You have been logged on with a temporary profile.
>
> Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off. Please see the event log for details or contact your administrator.

Did you delete those user profiles from the Windows XP machine recently?

This error can happen if you have recently deleted that user profile from the Windows machine.
You can try doing this https://support.microsoft.com/kb/947242, it says Windows Vista in the article but I remember doing the same thing on XP and Windows 7.

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. Log on to the system by using an administrative user account other
   than the user account that is experiencing the problem.
2. Back up all
   data in the current user's profile folder if the profile folder
   still exists, and then delete the profile folder. By default, the
   profile resides in the following location:
   %SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\UserName
3. Click Start, type regedit in the Start
   Search box, and then press ENTER.
4. Locate the
   following registry subkey:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
5. Under the ProfileList subkey, delete
   the subkey that is named SID.bak.

   Note SID is a placeholder for the security identifier (SID) of the
   user account that is experiencing the problem. The SID.bak subkey
   should contain a ProfileImagePath registry entry that points to the
   original profile folder of the user account that is experiencing the
   problem.
6. Exit Registry Editor.
7. Log off the system.
8. Log on to the
   system again.

After you log on to the system, the profile folder is re-created.

EDIT:

For the error you mentioned in the comments you should check if the network path for the profile is available from that workstation and if the correct permission are applied to it.

Comment: showing this error
Windows cannot locate the server copy of your roaming profile and is attempting to log you on with your local profile. Changes to the profile will not be copied to the server when you logoff. Possible causes of this error include network problems or insufficient security rights. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator.

Comment: open in system local administrator. but not showing that TEMP account in %SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\

Comment: Click on Detail, do you get this message when you click it "The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.", it is possible that the server share for the profile isn't accessible by DNS, or that the users don't have rights to the share. What is you Domain Controller is it Ubuntu with SAMBA, what is the Ubuntu server you mentioned in the question?

Comment: ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Comment: yes ubuntu with samba

Comment: So Ubuntu is your domain controller? Is it your only domain controller? You should add that data to the original question, the more info you put in the question the more likely you will get an resolution to the problem

Comment: a person try to set this. He fixed a profile. that profile login working with different xp system.